# virtual url representing page contents but not a different .html file

Tags: jquery, html, url, web, picasa

I have a website that consists of a single page coded in html that uses jquery to load web albums from picasa into a container depending on the link that the user clicks on.  This works fine, but I want the content loaded into the page to coincide with a url.  At the moment, when one of the album links is clicked, the photos load and a '#' is appended to the url.  How can I append the album name to the url instead, and have the browser understand that this album name coincides with the content loaded on the page by jquery.

Additionally, I want to be able to send someone a link to my website: kornweissphotography.com/steven/albumname where albumname is the name of one of my web albums and have the appropriate images load into the page.

website: [www.kornweissphotography.com/steven](http://www.kornweissphotography.com/steven)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could append a category to the end of the # on the links.

So you when you click on on people, the url is `http://www.kornweissphotography.com/steven/#people`

You could then look at the url in with javascript to figure out what to load.

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure this is only possible using a server side scripting language (e.g. PHP) and rewriting the query string using the .htaccess file. I don't think client side languages can have any effect on the url